# Unity C# Singleton + non-singleton class both extending to the same parent class

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, inheritance, singleton

Say I have classes ChildA and ChildB, both which extend to class Parent. There should only be one instance of ChildA and multiple instances of ChildB. The reason why they both extend to Parent is because some of their variables and methods are the same. What would be the best way of going about this? I have tried using Singleton for ChildA but becuase it requires static fields/methods it seems to conflict with its parent class. Removing ChildA's parent class could solve this issue but it doesn't seem right because some of its methods and variables match that of ChildB. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why use singleton ? if i understand correct you should use inheritance :(

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the error\conflict you are getting?

Have tried the following code with no issues:

```
using System;

public class Parent
{
    protected int value;
}

public class ChildA: Parent
{
    public static ChildA self = null;
    
    public ChildA()
    {
        if (self == null)
            self = this;
        
        value = 10;
    }
    public int GetVal()
    {
        return(value);
    }
}

public class ChildB: Parent
{
    public ChildB()
    {
        value = 20;
    }
    public int GetVal()
    {
        return(value);
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new ChildA();
        ChildB obj = new ChildB();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Singleton ChildA: " + ChildA.self.GetVal());
        Console.WriteLine("Value of ChildB: " + obj.GetVal());
    }
}
```